# Overloaded constructors in a class

Tags: java, constructor

I'm doing a project with overloaded constructors in a class and I'm a little stuck, below is what I'm supposed to be doing with the overloaded constructors:

"One    that    allows  first,  middle, and last    names   to  be  passed  as  Strings with    an  int for age

One that    accepts a   Name    object  reference,  and an  age as  an  int

- Make  a   new Name    inside  Person, copying the references  for the parts   of  the name."

I'm not quite sure what to do with my code, here is what I got:

```
public class Person {
    int age;
    Name aPersonHasAName;
    Name newPerson = new Name();

    public Person(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, int age) {
        newPerson.firstName = firstName;
        newPerson.middleName = middleName;
        newPerson.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Person(Name aPersonHasAName, int age) {

    }

    public void details() {
        System.out.println(aPersonHasAName + " age: " + age);
    }

}
```

I'm just lost as to what I'm supposed to be typing. I believe I've done the first overloaded constructor, but I am new to this.

So what should I be doing to make this work with overloaded constructors?

I think having the code from the other two classes might help.

Here is PersonTester:

```
public class PersonTester {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Person person1 = new Person("a1", "b1", "c1", 11);
            Person person2 = new Person(new Name("a2", "b2", "c2"), 22);
            Person person3 = new Person(new Name("a3", "c3"), 33);
            Person person4 = new Person(new Name("a4"), 44);
            Person person5 = new Person(new Name(), 55);
            System.out.println(person1.details());
            System.out.println(person2.details());
            System.out.println(person3.details());
            System.out.println(person4.details());
            System.out.println(person5.details());
    }
}
```

Then here is the Name class:
    public class Name {
    String firstName;
    String middleName;
    String lastName;

```
public Name(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this(firstName, "", lastName);
}

public Name(String firstName) {
    this(firstName, "", "");
}

public Name() {
    this("", "", "");
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getFullName(String nameString) {
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    build.append(nameString);
    build.deleteCharAt(nameString.length() - 1);
    build.insert(0, build.hashCode());
    return build.toString();
}

}
```

The problem I am having now is the error message in PersonTester which is: The method println(boolean) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (void)

I just need to know what in which class needs to be fixed to make it work.

I am very new to Java and object oriented programming.

Comment: you already done it, if you got multiple constructors with not the same titles you have done your overloading

Comment: what's the definition of name?

Answer (score 1):

So far so good. But eventually you'll reach a point where you duplicate a fair bit of code.

The constructor

`public Person(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, int age) {`

is the most comprehensive one in the sense that it takes in all the possible data.

With the other constructors, say one that takes a last name and an age, you can use *delegating constructors*:

```
public Person(String lastName, int age) {
   this(null, null, lastName, age); /*calls the other constructor*/
}
```

If you can't make such an assumption then you'll need to split up the name string by hand.

Comment: I do not know how this is an answer since we don't know what the op really wants?!!!!!!! you should have flagged this post as unclear

Answer (score 0):

Updating your code:

```
public Person(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, int age) {
    newPerson.firstName = firstName;
    newPerson.middleName = 
    newPerson.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;   //<---- was missing in your code
}
```

And your second contructor may look like this:

```
public Person(Name aPersonHasAName, int age) {
    this.newPerson = aPersonHasAName;
    this.age = age;
}
```

These contructors are implemented as you needed. 
Notice that you already done your overloading, if you got multiple constructors with **not** the same titles you contructors overloading

Comment: your answer has been flagged as a low quality answer. please provide more information or explanation about your answer.

Comment: look at my asnwer now, I updated it so you would understand it better

Comment: I do not know how this is an answer since we don't know what the op really wants?!!!!!!!

Comment: What do you mean when you say OP ?

Comment: the person who asked the question

Comment: When you asking for new String object there are several ways to create it, theses are the String contructors, so also in your case you got that. Please try to understand it while you creating a new object of your Person class

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Person {
    int age;
    Name aPersonHasAName;

    public Person(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, int age) {
        aPersonHasAName = new Name();
        aPersonHasAName.firstName = firstName;
        aPersonHasAName.middleName = middleName;
        aPersonHasAName.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Person(Name aPersonHasAName, int age) {
        this.aPersonHasAName = aPersonHasAName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void details() {
        System.out.println(aPersonHasAName + " age: " + age);
    }
}
```

I guess it also depends on if Name has a constructor for firstName, middleName, lastName